# Linearization of non-linear program or other solver

Tags: linear-programming, or-tools, nonlinear-optimization

I have a linear program that represent a time series of actions (the variables are ordered). The objective function is MIN. For every variable I have the constraint
Xi <= max_value.

I want the constraint to represent the real world more precisely, so I need to change that constrain as follow:

if sum(X1,...,Xi-1) > some_value then Xi <= max_value_1, else Xi <= max_value_2.

Is there a way to make it linear?
If not, is there a ready made solver (like ortools) for this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Provided your variable are integral, or can be scaled up to be integral, you can use CP-SAT for this.

This is explained in the [section](https://github.com/google/or-tools/blob/stable/ortools/sat/docs/channeling.md#if-then-else-expressions) of the documentation.

Answer (score 0):

*if sum(X1,...,Xi-1) > some_value then Xi <= max_value_1, else Xi <= max_value_2*.

```
 y(i) = sum(X(1),...,X(i-1))
 y(i) <= (1-δ(i))*some_value + δ(i)*M
 y(i) >= δ(i)*(some_value+0.00001) - (1-δ(i))*M
 X(i) <= max_value_1*δ(i) + max_value_2*(1-δ(i))

 δ(i) ∈ {0,1}
```

Here `M` is a large enough constant, and `y` is an extra continuous variable.